# Android, change at build time package name and assets

Tags: android, build, package

I have a project in Android that I want to be able to copy in the assets from a folder outside of the IDE and set the package name and some strings at build time.

My fellow developers here at the company, on the iOS platform tell me they can create a build script in XCode to import the necessary resources at build time, I wonder if I can do something similar in Eclipse with Android.

Essentially I need to build the same app under a different package name with a different set of assets each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer is to use an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) for the common code and separate projects for each package name and assets.

You could definitely script this as part of an Ant build process -- I have no idea what capabilities Eclipse has in this area.